# Axis Zooming - translation issue - d3.js version 4 -

Tags: javascript, d3.js, zooming, axis

short version:
I am using Axis Zooming and normal Zooming. I combine both together and the Zooming works fine. Only problem is, that the translation is not working as I want it. The translation one the axes is not 1 to 1. It depends on the scale factor of the normal zoom, how the translation behaves.

my status:
I have a line graph, which has normal zooming. Additional to that I have Axis-Zooming. So if I am in the Y-axis area, I only want to zoom the Y-axis and only move the Y-axis around. The same for the X-Axis.

For that I used d3.zoom instance and called(zoom) on 3 different rectangles.

1. is covering the whole graph area
2. is covering only x-axis
3. is only covering y-axis

The transform is saved on the elements.
The zoom function applies all 3 different zoom transforms to the scale, when triggered.

Setting everything up:

```
graph.zoomXY = d3.zoom()
    .scaleExtent([-10, 1000]);

graph.overlayX = graph.g//.select(".axis.x")
    .append("rect")
    .attr("fill", "rgba(255,0,0,0.5)")
    .attr("width", graph.rectWidth)
    .attr("height", 15)
    .attr("y", graph.rectHeight)
    .call(graph.zoomXY);

graph.overlayY = graph.g//.select(".axis.y")
    .append("rect")
    .attr("fill", "rgba(255,0,0,0.5)")
    .attr("width", 150)
    .attr("height", graph.rectHeight)
    .attr("x", -150)
    .call(graph.zoomXY);

//append the rectangle to capture zoom
graph.overlayRect = graph.g.append("rect")
    .attr("class", "overlay-rect")
    .attr("width", graph.rectWidth)
    .attr("height", graph.rectHeight)
    .style("fill", "none")     
    .call(graph.zoomXY)
    .on("dblclick.zoom", function() {
        resetZoom();
    } );
```

Calculating Scale:

```
function zoomed() {

    getZoomedScales();
    updateGraph();

}

function getZoomedScales() {

    var transformX = d3.zoomTransform(graph.overlayX.node());
    var transformY = d3.zoomTransform(graph.overlayY.node());
    var transformXY = d3.zoomTransform(graph.overlayRect.node());

    graph.yScaleTemp = transformXY.rescaleY(transformY.rescaleY(graph.yScale));
    graph.xScaleTemp = transformXY.rescaleX(transformX.rescaleX(graph.xScale));

}
```

The Zooming is working fine. **But** the translation on the axes Zoom (graph.overlayY and graph.overlayX) is influenced by the Scaling factor of the zoom applied to graph.overlayRect. If I change the order, the issue will be just flipped. The axes Zoom's scale factor (graph.overlayY and graph.overlayX), messes up the translation of the Zoom on graph.overlayRect.

Open the fiddle and change the Zooming, while over the graph area. Then mousedown and mousemove on one  of the axes. Repeat and see how it changes the translation.

Here is a fiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/9j4kqq1v/

Comment: So, I checked the d3.js source code and I found the reason. D3.js v4 saves the zoom data on the dom-element, which is quite obvious. But when the onmousedowned is triggered and mousemove event is appended, it only uses the zoom data appended to that dom-element. Which means, that other scaling factors are not taken account for. So a work around would be, to apply the scale factor from the xy-zoom to the dom-elements for x-zoom and y-zoom, when mousedown is triggered and revert it, when mosueup is triggered. This way, the dragging works properly.

Comment: Thank you for posting your jsfiddle. It was super helpful!!