# d3.js: brusing in a domain driven chart and get the data

Tags: javascript, d3.js

The x axis of my chart is manipulated with a domain:

```
var xScale = d3
 .scaleLinear()
 .domain([
   0,
   d3.max(Object.keys(signalData), (d) => signalData[d].data.length),
 ]) 
 .range([0, width]);
```

When I now drag a brush over the (line)chart i want to get the y values of the path.
I tried something like this:

```
function brushTest() {
  const sel = d3.brushSelection(this);
  console.log(sel);
  var j = signalData(function (d) {
    return d >= sel[0] && d <= sel[1]
  });
  console.log(j);
}
```

But i get the wong data... However i think the problem is, that i have to work with the "domained" data. How is this possible?

Comment: What do you mean by y values of the path? Do you want to get the y values for all data points inside the brushed area? In that case, get the x values of the brush's left and right side and filter your data set for that range.

Comment: Yes exactly. But if I do it this way im getting wrong data, because im adding a domain. My Data array has 5999 values but because of the domain the highest value i can get from the Brush is something round about 1900. (the chart width is depending on the browser window Size)

Comment: I do not get the "adding a domain" part. What do you mean by that? The x domain also does not end at the end of your screen. The scale uses the domain min and max value to create a linear function to project your data into the horizontal pixel line. It will also work for values, which will be outside of the screen area. The scale also works in the other direction, you can put in a pixel value and get the actual value returned.

Comment: So if I understood it right if my `xScale` is declared like you can see on the top the command  `console.log(xScale(width));` should give me back the last value at the end of the chart? How can i get  the matching y value to an `xScale(x)` value if you put in a random number for `x`?

Comment: You need to call xScale.invert(width); That will give you the corresponding value in the domain.

Comment: And another thing is, that i can zoom in the chart in wich I want to get the data. Now the data wich i get back is wrong. How can i fix this? The problem is, that the width is always the same and does not change when i zoom in. Is it possible to get the datapints straight form the path?

Comment: It is pretty straight forward to do, what you want. If you provide a working demo, I can write you an answer with the working solution. Maybe have a look at this chart I made a while ago. There is a marker put on the closest data point. That might help you also find a solution: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40178425/axis-zooming-translation-issue-d3-js-version-4

Comment: I took a look on you SO post but i cant realy figgure out how i can implement this for my solution. I added you a [jsfiddle example](https://jsfiddle.net/q36t1we9/) maybe you can take a look here. On the area chart i only zoom into all the other linecharts. In the linecharts I want to brush an area and get the selected datapoints form of the path. I hope you understood what i want to archive... if not just feel free to ask. Thank you very much.